# How to identify the the sql exec() execute a command properly

Tags: sql

If i run a sql EXEC() command, then how i confirm that the command is executed properly.Because i don't find any success/failure return type of this command.
Let say my command is:

```
EXEC('INSERT into '+@t1+'('+@c1+') values ('+@v1+')')
```

or any other way to be confirm that, the command is execute properly into the destination table.

Comment: You're saying **sql** (which is the *Structured Query Language* - a **language**, not a database product) - but you're really meaning **SQL Server** (the Microsoft RDBMS product) - right?? Please tag accordingly! Please use `sql-server` instead of just `sql` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use global variable `@@rowcount` after a exec command:

```
select @@rowcount
```

It displays rows affected by the last command.

If you want to catch an exception:

```
BEGIN TRY
   EXEC('fake code') 
   select @@rowcount -- if exec works correctly 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT N'Your message';
END CATCH;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms175976.aspx) about `try-catch`.

Comment: Bear in mind that after something invalid like `exec('select * from doesnotexist')` `@@rowcount` would be 1 also

Comment: very good point. Then how we handle the case.Is there any way?

Comment: sp_executesql with an output param of @rows=@@rowcount would do it

Comment: @riad For `exec('select * from doesnotexist')` you can also use `try-catch` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms175976.aspx))

Comment: Thanks but i use it into a stored procedure

Comment: @riad You can use it in a stored procedure